# unusual result in measuring time in python

Tags: python, performance, time

This is my stopwatch class

```
import time

class StopWatch:

    def __init__(self, tag="", startTime=time.time(), elapsedTime=-1):
        self._tag=tag
        self._elapsedTime=elapsedTime
        self._startTime=startTime

    # other codes here............#

    def stop(self, tag=None):
        if tag is not None:
            self._tag = tag
        self._elapsedTime = time.time() - self._startTime
        return self

    def getStartTime(self):
        return self._startTime
```

And stopwatch test file is:

```
import unittest
import time
from metric.StopWatch import StopWatch

class StopWatchTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_stopwatch(self):
        now=time.time()
        print "now:%f" % now

        stopwatch=StopWatch("firstHook")
        print "start time:%r" % stopwatch.getStartTime()
        self.assertTrue(stopwatch.getStartTime()>now, "start time is wrong")
```

What I get is error with:

```
now:1364791630.047630
start time:1364791629.158797
```

..

```
AssertionError: start time is wrong
```

The code to be executed later is showing earlier time. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated only once.

```
def __init__(self, tag="", startTime=time.time(), elapsedTime=-1):
    self._tag=tag
    self._elapsedTime = elapsedTime
    self._startTime = startTime
```

To fix, we need to check the defaults explicitly and evaluate them in the function body:

```
def __init__(self, tag="", startTime=None, elapsedTime=-1):
    self._tag=tag
    self._elapsedTime = elapsedTime
    if startTime is None:
        startTime = time.time()
    self._startTime = startTime
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that this line:

```
def __init__(self, tag="", startTime=time.time(), elapsedTime=-1):
```

Is evaluated when it is reached by the Python interpreter (because despite the name it actually compiles the code, albeit to byte code). So startTime is set when the class is defined, not when `__init__` is called.

Change it to:

```
def __init__(self, tag="", start_time=None, elapsed_time=-1):
    if start_time is None:
        start_time = time.time()
    self._tag=tag
    self._elapsed_time=elapsed_Time
    self._start_time=start_time
```